# $SU(2)$ gauge SUSY with Affleck-Dine-Seiberg term

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry, quantum-chromodynamics, non-perturbative

Consider SUSY gauge theory with $SU(2)$ group and matter fields $Q$ and $\bar{Q}$ in fundamental and anti-fundamental representations correspondently and the following superpotential:

$$W=\frac{{\Lambda}^5}{\bar{Q}Q}+m\bar{Q}Q$$

the first term is Affleck-Dine-Seiberg (ADS)-like term and the second is just mass term. I'm trying to find a space of vacua in such theory. Since $Q$ and $\bar{Q}$ have the following form

$$Q_{A}=q_{A}+\sqrt{2}\theta\psi_{A}-{\theta}^2f_{A}$$
$$\bar{Q}_{A}=\bar{q}_{A}+\sqrt{2}\theta\bar{\psi}_{A}-{\theta}^2\bar{f}_{A}$$

And to find the vacuum, one must go to the potential of scalar fields. I have found that potential for scalar fields is given by

$$V=\frac{{\Lambda}^{10}(\bar{q}^{\dagger}\bar{q}+q^{\dagger}q)}{(q^{\dagger}\bar{q}^{\dagger})^2(q\bar{q})^2}+m^2(\bar{q}^{\dagger}\bar{q}+q^{\dagger}q)+2\Lambda^5m(\bar{q}^{\dagger}\bar{q}+q^{\dagger}q)\left(\frac{1}{(q^{\dagger}\bar{q}^{\dagger})^2}+\frac{1}{(q\bar{q})^2}\right)$$

And I am a little bit confused of this form. But my professor have said that "*This potential looks quite reasonable*".

But to be honest, I don't quite understand how to find the vacuum of such potential. Can I somehow simplify such an expression using gauge transformations? Can I pick fields as follows with $SU(2)$ help:
$$q_A=  \begin{bmatrix}
           \phi\\
0
         \end{bmatrix}$$

And for $\bar{q}_A$
$$\bar{q}_A=  \begin{bmatrix}
           \bar{\phi}\\
0
         \end{bmatrix}$$

where $\phi$ and $\bar{\phi}$ lie in fundamental and anti-fundamental representations